# DevExtreme dxDataGrid in asp.net application as detail's view.

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been using 3rd party components like devexpress/devExtreme for a couple of great projects. I have a scenario where i have to use a devextreme dxDataGrid Widget in one of my asp.net application as details view.
I am new to asp.net. I have a two SQL tables having one to many relationship. In typical Devexpress XAF application, the xpCollection<> is there that indicates that this particular class has a collection of objects(One-many relationship). The XAf framework handles the creation of a new object whenever we click on create new through its session. Now i want to achieve a similar thing in my asp.net application by using Devextreme dxDataGrid widget as a collection of the objects in a class. I would like to have a simple short example to understand the implementation of such a scenario managing CRUD operations.

Thanks & Regards,
Naser Javed.

Comment: Here http://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/#demo/data_grid-paging_and_scrolling-record_paging there is a lot of examples of usage the dxDataGrid widget. All demos contain a code samples, as well.

Comment: I have gone through lots of examples yet i can't figure out how to integrate my requirements using dxDataGrid widget in a simple asp.net (not MVC) application. Thank u for ur effort @Sergey